# Roll join gives NA's in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Sample data:

```
Usage = data.table(
  feature = 'M11', 
  startDate = structure(rep(17130, 17155, c(4, 3)), class = "Date"), 
  cc = 'X6', vendor = 'Z1'
)
Limits = data.table(
  vendorId = 'Z1',
  featureId = 'M11', 
  costcenter ='X6', oldLimit = 1:6, 
  date = structure(17044 + c(91, 61, 30, 0, 105, 75), class = "Date")
)
```

I am trying to add a column `limit` to the `Usage` `data.table` by looking at the `Limits` `data.table`. This is to find out what was the limit for that `feature`, `costCenter`, `vendor` combination at the time of its corresponding usage.

However when I try to roll-join using the below code, I get strange results. I get lot of `NA`s for my data, so created sample data as above. Below is my roll-join code.

```
Usage[Limits, limitAtStartDate:= i.oldLimit,   
      on = c(cc="costcenter", feature="featureId",
             vendor="vendorId", startDate="date" ), 
      roll=TRUE, verbose=TRUE][] 
#    feature  startDate cc vendor limitAtStartDate
# 1:     M11 2016-11-25 X6     Z1                6
# 2:     M11 2016-11-25 X6     Z1               NA
# 3:     M11 2016-11-25 X6     Z1               NA
# 4:     M11 2016-11-25 X6     Z1               NA
# 5:     M11 2016-12-20 X6     Z1                5
# 6:     M11 2016-12-20 X6     Z1               NA
# 7:     M11 2016-12-20 X6     Z1               NA
```

Why is that `5` & `6` are set only for one record for `limitAtStartDate`?

I am expecting `5` for all rows with date `2016-12-20` and `6` for all `2016-11-25`. Please let me know where I am going wrong. I am using `data.table` version `1.10.0`.

Comment: I think you are doing it the other way around. Try `Limits[Usage, oldLimit, on=.(costcenter=cc, featureId = feature, vendorId = vendor, date = startDate), roll = TRUE]` Also, please don't forget `setDT(Usage) ; setDT(Limits)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks for this. Updated question and result with proper setDT(). But I donot want to join the other way around as I would not get the correct DT structure afterwards.

Comment: I got you the values you need. You can put them back into the `Usage` table. E.g. `Usage[, limitAtStartDate := Limits[Usage, oldLimit, on=.(costcenter = cc, featureId = feature, vendorId = vendor, date = startDate), roll = TRUE]]`

Comment: Ahh!! right. I got this now. Thanks ! This answers my question. I shall accept this.

Comment: Btw, you could also just do `setorder(Limits, date)[findInterval(Usage$startDate, date), oldLimit]` for the simple cases

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. This introduces me to findInterval function which I can use in such simple cases. T

Comment: @DavidArenburg can you please post this as the answer for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When performing an `X[Y]` join in `data.table` what you are basically doing is for each value in `Y` you are trying to find a value in `X`. Hence, the resulting join will be of length of the `Y`s table. In your case, you are trying to find a value in `Limits` for each value in `Usage` and get a 7 length vector. Hence, you probably should join the other way around and then store it back into `Limits`

```
Limits[Usage, 
       oldLimit, 
       on = .(costcenter = cc, featureId = feature, vendorId = vendor, date = startDate),
       roll = TRUE]
## [1] 6 6 6 6 5 5 5
```

---

As a side note, for very (and some times not so) simple cases you could just use `findInterval`.

```
setorder(Limits, date)[findInterval(Usage$startDate, date), oldLimit]
## [1] 6 6 6 6 5 5 5
```

It is a very efficient function that have some caveats though

- You need to sort the intervals vector first.
- You can't set the rolling intervals easily as you would do in `data.table` (e.g. `roll = 2` instead of just `roll = TRUE`)
- And probably the biggest disadvantage is that it will be tricky to perform a rolling join on several variables at once (without involving loops) as you would easily do with `data.table`